# Cannot launch the app - "Emulator-5556 [DISCONNECTED]" keeps appearing and disappearing

Tags: android-studio

Android Studio functions correctly for the most part, but I can't seem to use the emulator.

In the deployment target menu an emulator called `emulator-5556 [DISCONNECTED]` keeps appearing and disappearing about once a second. It always starts about 10 seconds after `adb` is initialized, when I open the run menu for the first time.

Whenever it does this, I cannot seem to run my app on the emulator, or on my own phone. The emulator starts up, but the app never gets launched. I've had the issue on every project I've opened.

In the run log this message appears whenever the issue is occurring and I try to run the program:

```
Device emulator-5556disconnected, monitoring stopped
```

I've also made a [screen capture](https://youtu.be/qNJYFAykTvM) of the issue.

I found some other threads talking about other problems with disconnected emulators being fixed with the `kill-server` and `start-server` command, so I tried this, and while this does stop the issue for a little bit, it starts flashing the disconnected emulator again in the menu 10 seconds after I reopen the run menu.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

I've tried:

- Restarting `adb` with `kill-server` and then `start-server`
- uninstalling Android Studio and reinstalling it
- deleting the SDK files and reinstalling them
- deleting `gradle`, and reinstalling it
- I've rebooted the computer multiple times

I think it's unlikely to be a computer related issue since I know several other people with the exact same laptop who didn't run into this issue.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The issue was that I had VideoStream installed on my laptop, which was using port 5556. Uninstalling the app fixed the problem.

Comment: Fixed it for me too.

Comment: I contacted videostream support about this, but they have no plans to fix it :(

Comment: save me lots of time, thanks