# Android studio 3.4 does not launch app on run

Tags: android

I installed Android Studio 3.4 on a new laptop (Macbook), and running the `app` configuration now only installs the APK, but does not run the specified Activity.

- The Activity is marked as `android.intent.action.MAIN` and `android.intent.category.LAUNCHER`
- The Run configuration is set up to launch the `Default activity`. Also tried specifying the exact Activity to run, no use.
- As per some other S/O threads, tried disabling Instant run, that did not help.
- Launching the Activity through `adb` works - `am start -n cz.melkamar.pkg/cz.melkamar.pkg.MainActivity`
- Tried downgrading to AS 3.3.2, still nothing.
- Created a fresh project, running that still did not launch the default Activity

I'm at a loss, any idea which settings/configs I should look at?

Comment: Have you tried other devices/emulators? Or is this affecting all of them?

Comment: Affects the emulator and my hardware device too

Comment: Probably from videostream : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54721760/cannot-launch-the-app-emulator-5556-disconnected-keeps-appearing-and-disap/54731956#54731956

Comment: Holy hell, I do have Videostream installed. I'll give this a shot

Comment: @Emmanuel actually worked, thanks! If you post this as an answer, I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Emmanuel suggested in a comment, the reason was that the Videostream app was clashing with the same port. Uninstalling it solved my issue.

Source link: [Cannot launch the app - "Emulator-5556 [DISCONNECTED]" keeps appearing and disappearing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54721760/cannot-launch-the-app-emulator-5556-disconnected-keeps-appearing-and-disap/54731956#54731956)